# Cual es la diferencia entre delete vs delete[] vs free(...)

Tags: c++, manejo-de-memoria

Estoy aprendiendo C++ y encuentro que hay diferentes formas de liberar la memoria dinámica (`delete`, `delete[]`, `free(...)`) y no se para que casos usarlas, ¿Alguien me puede sacar de esta confusión?, Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) categoriza la gestión de memoria en funciones de alojado y funciones de des-alojado, como puede verse en el apartado 3.7.4.1 (traducción mía):

> #### 3.7.4 Duración de Almacenamiento Dinámico
>
> Los objetos pueden ser creados dinámicamente durante la ejecución del programa, usando *expresiones-new*, y destruidos usando *expresiones-delete*. Las implementaciones de C++ proporciona acceso y gestión a la meomria dinámica mediante las funciones globales de alojamiento `operator new` y `operator new[]` y funciones globales de des-alojamiento `operator delete` y `operator delete[]`.

Esas son las funciones de alojado y des-alojado de memoria que C++ ofrece, la variante con corchetes (`[]`) se usa para alojar o des-alojar memoria de formaciones<sup>1</sup>. La función de des-alojamiento de memoria [`std::free` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/free) pertenece a C, no a C++, es posible usarla en código de C++ y es la única manera de liberar memoria alojada por [`std::malloc` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc).

A grandes rasgos, toda la memoria alojada mediante funciones de C++ (`new` y `new[]`) debe ser des-alojada mediante funciones de C++ (`delete` y `delete[]`) mientras que toda la memoria alojada mediante la función de alojado de C (`std::malloc`) debe ser des-alojada mediante la función de des-alojado C (`std::free`).

Si analizamos con más detalle las funciones de alojado y des-alojado de C++ y C:

C++: `new`/`new[]` con `delete`/`delete[]`:

- Si el alojado de memoria falla, se lanza una excepción [`std::bad_alloc` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc).
- El retorno de `new`/`new[]` tiene tipado fuerte, también es de tipado fuerte el parámetro que recibe `delete`/`delete[]`.

  - El tamaño del objeto para el que se aloja/des-aloja memoria es calculado automáticamente por el compilador través del tipo.
- La versión para objetos (`new`/`delete`) está explícitamente separada de la versión para formaciones (`new[]`/`delete[]`).
- Se puede sobrecargar.

C: `std::malloc` con `std::freee`:

- Si el alojado de memoria falla, se devuelve un puntero nulo.
- El retorno de `std::malloc` carece de información de tipo, tampoco dispone de información de tipo el parámetro que recibe `std::free`.

  - El tamaño del objeto para el que se aloja/des-aloja memoria debe calcularlo el programador.
- Se usa la misma rutina de alojamiento para objetos y para formaciones.
- No se puede personalizar.

---

1. También conocidas como *arreglos* o en inglés *arrays*.

Answer (score 5):

`free` es una función heredada de C. En C no existe el concepto de clases y objetos. Es un lenguaje procedural puro y duro. Bajo este contexto, para trabajar con memoria dinámica nos encontramos con tres funciones básicas:

- `malloc`: Función que reserva un bloque de memoria y te devuelve un puntero al inicio de dicho bloque.
- `realloc`: Función que permite agrandar o reducir el bloque de memoria reservado previamente. Si se le pasa un bloque nulo funciona igual que `malloc`.
- `free`: Función que libera la memoria reservada previamente con `malloc`.

También existe la función `calloc`, pero no la he incluído en esta lista porque esta función es más bien compuesta. Esta función hace una reserva de memoria, al igual que `malloc` y, seguidamente, inicializa todos los bytes de dicha reserva a un valor determinado.

En C++ la cosa cambia. C++ es un lenguaje orientado a objetos y, por esta razón, dispone de una serie de utilidades que facilitan el trabajo con objetos. En el caso de la gestión con memoria dinámica tenemos las siguientes funciones:

- `new`: Esta función es la hermana mayor de `calloc`. Aparte de reservar un bloque de memoria lo suficientemente grande, invoca automáticamente al constructor para que se inicialice la memoria con valores adecuados.
- `delete`: Esta función se encarga de invocar al destructor del objeto para, seguidamente, liberar el bloque de memoria.

Estas dos funciones solo sirven para crear elementos sueltos, de uno en uno. Para aquellos casos en los que es necesario crear arrays de elementos tenemos a nuestra disposición una versión de `new` y `delete` específica. Esta versión se caracteriza por tener corchetes:

```
int* elementoSuelto = new int(10); // Un unico entero, valor 10
int* array = new int[5](10); // 5 enteros, todos valen 10

delete elementoSuelto;
delete[] array;
```

Llegados a este punto conviene destacar que es importante saber qué versión de `delete` hay que usar en cada momento. Si creamos un elemento con `new` tendremos que usar `delete`, pero si se crea con `new[]` entonces debermos usar de `delete[]`. Si mezclamos los usos nos podremos encontrar con comportamientos erráticos, fugas de memoria y otros problemas al ejecutar la aplicación.

Pues bien, resumiendo, estas son las principales diferencias entre las funciones que comentas:

- `free`: Es la más simple de todas. Esta función se limita a marcar como libre el bloque de memoria que se pasa por puntero.
- `delete`: Utilidad propia de C++. Esta función invoca al destructor del objeto y, finalmente, libera la memoria reservada por el mismo
- `delete[]`: Similar a la utilidad anterior, está pensada para borrar arrays de objetos.

Answer (score 3):

Estuve mirando información en [Este libro](https://goalkicker.com/CPlusPlusBook/) en el capitulo 104.11 y encontré esto:

```
int* p1 = new int;
delete p1; // correct
// delete[] p1; // undefined
// free(p1); // undefined


int* p2 = new int[10];
delete[] p2; // correct
// delete p2; // undefined
// free(p2); // undefined


int* p3 = static_cast<int*>(malloc(sizeof(int)));
free(p3); // correct
// delete p3; // undefined
// delete[] p3; // undefined
```

- `delete`: 
  Un objeto que fue creado con `new` y no es un array solo puede liberar la memoria con `delete`
- `delete[]`:
  Un objeto que sea creado con `new __[..]` o con `char *` solo puede liberar la memoria con `delete[]` ya que no solo tiene un posición de memoria si no que tiene una cadena de memoria
- `free(...)`:
  Un Objeto el cual apartó memoria con `malloc(sizeof(...))` solo puede liberar la memoria con `free(...)`