# Segmentation fault C++

Tags: c++, lista, punteros, manejo-de-memoria

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct nodeDouble{
  int data;
  nodeDouble* next;
  nodeDouble* prev;
};

nodeDouble* head;
nodeDouble* tail;

void addNode(int number){
  if(head == NULL){
    head = (nodeDouble*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeDouble));
    head->data = number;
    head->next = NULL;
    head->prev = NULL;
    tail = head;
  }else{
    tail->next = (nodeDouble*)malloc(sizeof(struct nodeDouble));
    tail->next->data = number;
    tail->next->prev = tail;
    head->next->next = NULL;
    tail = tail->next;
  }
}

void printList(nodeDouble* headList){

  while(headList != NULL){
    cout << headList->data << "\n";
    headList = headList->next;
  }
  headList = NULL;
}

int main(){
  for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
    addNode(i);

  }
  printList(head);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Prueba a inicializar head y tail a null

Answer (score 3):

Fíjate en esta línea aparentemente inofensiva (se encuentra en `addNode`):

```
head->next->next = NULL;
```

Esta línea está **rompiendo** tu lista enlazada. En el momento en el que añadas tres elementos, esta línea cortará la lista. Es decir, tu lista quedará así:

```
head                    tail
node -> node -> null    node -> null
```

Cuando tu esperas que quede así:

```
head            tail
node -> node -> node -> null
```

Y claro, si tu iteras desde `head` hasta `tail` sin comprobar punteros acabas encontrándote con ese tercer nodo que es `null` y ahí empiezan los problemas.

Dado que estás en C++ te sugiero, al igual que hacen en la otra respuesta, que dejes de usar `malloc` y pases a usar `new`. Junto con este cambio, define un constructor apropiado y el problema se solucionará *solo*:

```
struct nodeDouble{
  int data;
  nodeDouble* next;
  nodeDouble* prev;

  nodeDouble(int value)
    : data(value),
      next(nullptr),
      prev(nullptr)
  { }
};

nodeDouble* head = nullptr;
nodeDouble* tail = nullptr;

void addNode(int number){
  nodeDouble * node = new nodeDouble(number);

  if(head == nullptr){
    head = node;
  }else{
    tail->next = node;
    node->prev = tail;
  }

  tail = node;
}
```

Lo que sucede ahora es que `new` invoca, implícitamente, al constructor que hemos declarado en la clase. Este constructor inicializa los punteros `next` y `prev` a `nullptr` (sustituto natural de `NULL` en el estándar C++11). Además también inicializa `data` a partir de un valor que le facilitamos.

Posteriormente solo actualizaremos aquellos punteros que necesitemos y listo, la lista estará correctamente enlazada.

También prodríamos crear un constructor un poco más *completo*:

```
struct nodeDouble{
  int data;
  nodeDouble* next;
  nodeDouble* prev;

  nodeDouble(int value, nodeDouble* previous)
    : data(value),
      next(nullptr),
      prev(previous)
  {
    if( nullptr != previous )
      previous->next = this;
  }
};

nodeDouble* head = nullptr;
nodeDouble* tail = nullptr;

void addNode(int number){
  nodeDouble * node = new nodeDouble(number,tail);

  if(head == nullptr)
    head = node;

  tail = node;
}
```

Ahora el constructor recibe también un puntero al nodo anterior. Si este puntero es nulo no hace nada, pero si no lo es se *añade* al final de la lista, por lo que solo faltaría actualizar `tail`.

Answer (score 1):

#### Los Nodos no son Listas.

Este es un error recurrente en StackOverflow en Español que genera mucha confusión.

En el código que has facilitado estás pasando variables de tipo `nodeDouble` con nombre de lista y eso es tan erróneo como decir que un escalón es una escalera, sinceramente ¿Te parecen lo mismo?:

[image]
[image]

#### La nomenclatura es importante.

Además de la incorrecta nomenclatura que confunde nodos con listas, tu nodo se llama `nodeDouble` pero los datos contenidos son `int` ¿Seguro que estás haciendo lo que quieres?

#### Tu pregunta es sobre C++.

La cabecera [`<stdio.h>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) es de [c](/questions/tagged/c) no de [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). Esta cabecera dispone de una versión adaptada a C++ que tiene el prefijo **`c`** y carece de extensión. Si realmente necesitas usar las cabeceras de C (que nunca será el caso) debes usar los equivalentes de C++ [`<cstdio>` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdio). Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/48268/2742) para saber por qué.

La función de alojamiento de memoria [`std::malloc` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/malloc) pertenece a C, no a C++. En C++ se usa `new` que lanza una excepción ([`std::bad_alloc` [image]](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc)) si falla al alojar memoria, tiene tipado fuerte, el tamaño del objeto para el que se aloja memoria es calculado por el compilador a través del tipo, separa el alojado de objetos del de formaciones y se puede sobrecargar. Lee [este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/199221/2742) para saber más.

El lenguaje C++ es multiparadigma, así que a priori no estás limitado a un paradigma concreto; pero uno de los puntos fuertes del lenguaje es su soporte a la [programación orientada a objetos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n_orientada_a_objetos) así que te aconsejo que realmente crees un objeto lista en lugar de confiar en funciones sueltas.

#### Propuesta.

Teniendo en cuenta todo lo anterior, tu código podría tener este aspecto:

```
class Lista
{
    struct node{
      int data = 0;
      node* next = nullptr;
      node* prev = nullptr;
    };

    node* head = nullptr;
    node* tail = nullptr;

    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &, const Lista &);

public:
    void add(int number);
};
```

La clase `Lista` dispone de una clase interna en la zona privada que es el `node`; esta clase privada es inaccesible desde fuera favoreciendo el [encapsulamiento](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulamiento_(inform%C3%A1tica)): la propia clase gestiona sus nodos, desde fuera de la lista no hay motivos para trabajar con nodos, he renombrado `addNode` a `add` por ese motivo.

Con este código, la implementación de `add` podría parecerse a:

```
void Lista::add(int number)
{
    if (tail)
    {
        tail = tail->next = new node{number, nullptr, tail};
    }
    else
    {
        head = tail = new node{number};
    }
}
```

El código anterior aprovecha que `node` es un agregado para poder asignar valores al construir; en la propia construcción se enlaza con los nodos correspondientes.

También he substituido la función `printList` por una función amiga que escribe en el flujo de salida, pudiendo usar la lista así:

```
Lista l;
l.add(3);
l.add(2);
l.add(1);

std::cout << l;
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en [<kbd>Wandbox</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ybtRKfNbGMOcOrJZ).

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a inicializar head y tail a null:

```
nodeDouble* head = NULL;
nodeDouble* tail = NULL;
```

Aunque en C++ deberías evitar usar punteros (o, si tienes que usarlos, intenta usar smart pointers, como std::unique_ptr). Si vas a usar punteros, intenta usar nullptr (en vez de NULL).

Por otro lado, intenta evitar malloc (en la gran mayoría de casos, usar malloc es undefined behavior en C++), usa new:

```
head = new nodeDouble();
```

Comment: lo del *undefined behavior* con `malloc` solo se puede producir si se usa con objetos que requieran inicialización (que no es el caso). Aun así coincido en que es una mala práctica.

Comment: No únicamente en ese caso, usando malloc el valor de cualquier variable (excepto si el tipo es unsigned char) podría ser un trap value (lo que significaría undefined behavior simplemente leyéndola)

Comment: eso no es cierto. Te pongo por ejemplo el tipo `int`. Cualquier valor almacenado en dicha variable sería válido... otra cosa es que no esté inicializado... y lo mismo sería aplicable a `short`, `char` (aparecerían caracteres no imprimibles), `unsigned char`, `long long`, ...

Comment: No. Por ejemplo, un caso claro es un float: si no lo inicializas, puede que acabes con un "signalled NaN", que, dependiendo de la FPU, puede lanzar inmediatamente una excepción (que será procesada en la FPU). Puedes leer más en el standard, si estás interesado: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2091.htm

Comment: Lo primero es que un proposal no es el estándar sino una propuesta que puede o no formar parte del estándar en el futuro. Por otro lado un float con NaN no va a lanzar una excepción... siempre podrás inicializar la variable (que es justamente  lo que hace el constructor). En asignaciones no se comprueba el valor previo. No tienes bien organizadas esas ideas

Comment: Además, la propuesta es para C, no para C++...

Comment: Sin ofender, creo que eres tú quien no tiene claras las ideas. Por supuesto que un float con NaN puede lanzar una excepción (en concreto, una excepción en la FPU, como yo he dicho), tú estás mezclando conceptos (excepción no es algo que se aplique solo al lenguaje, en el hardware se lanzan excepciones también). Puedes leer más aquí https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/fenv
El pdf que añadí era para que pudieras leer más información sobre signalling NaNs (que son los que pueden lanzar una excepción en la FPU)

Comment: el NaN **puede** dar comportamiento indefinido **si usas** la variable no inicializada. Si le asignas valores la estás inicializando y desde ese momento funcionará correctamente. Y eso es independiente del lenguaje